# Radio button "selected" value changed in Model but not changed in View in Angular 5

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular5

```
<div class=""  [ngClass]="( listItemStyle + ' ' + (showListColomn ? 'multi-columns' : '') )" *ngIf="type == 'radio' " (click)="onSelect(data)">
  <surf-radiobutton
    [selected]="data.selected"
    [disabled]="data.disabled"
    [lable]=data.name
    [code]=data.code
    [showNameCode]="showCode"
    [group]="group"
  >
  </surf-radiobutton>
</div>
```

In onSelect(data) method, data.selected value set to the true if it is false. set false if it is true. surf-radiobutton is created radio button module. [selected]="data.selected" make radio button selected of not. 
when click the radio button onSelect(data) method triggered and data.selected value set to true but in frontend data.selected value did not changed. It keeps false continuously.

Comment: Try to change selected property as two-way Data Binding like this [(selected)]="data.selected"

Comment: I tried but did not work.

Comment: Where you are getting data value in .ts file. Post some code so that we can analyse and tell.

Comment: Solved. It because of variable I used. It reset when angular component refresh. Thanks for helping @Vignesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It because of an array I used. It reset when angular component refresh. item is element of that array.